# jQuery Selectors - where item does not have children with a certain class

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I want to select list items that are immediate children of #nav, that do not themselves have immediate children with an 'active' class.

This is what I think it should be but it does not work:

```
$('#nav > li:not(> a.active)')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to use jQuery's `filter` function:

```
$('#nav > li').filter(function() { return !($(this).children().is('.active')); })
```

Comment: This is even better than your first solution. I think you should have kept that one around though as an alternate. Or was there a problem with it?

Comment: No, this one seems to work intermittently.  I'm reverting back to previous answer.

Comment: This will return li elements that don't have active, I don't believe it will check the children of the li elements for the active class.

Comment: I think **Jeremy B.** is right. The 'selector only' solution doesn't seem to test against the children, but rather the `li` only.

Comment: I agree.  Taking out the selector-only answer and leaving `filter`

Comment: @Ken: Good call. I was going to offer an answer that used `each()`, but `filter()` is a *much* nicer solution.

Comment: Thanks Ken, this is perfect...and thanks everyone else for their help!

Comment: @Trevor, glad you found your answer and welcome to Stackoverflow!  Please click on the check mark by Ken's answer so he gets credit for the solution.

Comment: @Trevor, this is not how you do it! See my answer: $('#nav > li:not(:has(a.active))'). I do not think you accepted the best answer.

Answer (score 28):

This is how you do it:

```
    $('#nav > li:not(:has(a.active))')
```

Answer (score 3):

I really like Ken's solution, but just for an alternative take.

You could add the active class to your list items instead of your links inside.  Then your selector could look like:

```
$("ul#nav li:not(.active)");
```

If you want to style the links based on the active class, your CSS could look like this:

```
#nav li.active a{background-color:red;}
```

Comment: Why has this answer been downvoted twice?  If it is incorrect, which part does not work and how can I improve it?

Comment: This answer is incorrect because it returns the children of `li`. Trevor wants the `li` elements themselves. Re-read the question.

Comment: Thank you!  I missed that part, I will change my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

For this jquery has the [not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector

you can do something like

```
$("#nav > li").children(":not(.active)");
```

Comment: This is not what Trevor is looking for. He wants **children of #nav, that do not themselves have immediate children with an 'active' class**.

Comment: missed one of the children in there, fixed that.

Comment: The elements he wants to select are the li elements.  Your selector would return their children.

Comment: Good point, the wording is a bit challenging but I see what he's looking for, will look back at that again.